# Why is the mount() syscall not picking up a selinuxfs path?

Tags: android, c, linux, system-calls, init

I am trying to port Android to an x86 device, but the question should be universal. My kernel tree is the `android13-5.15` (so kernel 5.15) branch, and I am using the LineageOS source code from the master branch to build userspace.

When the first stage `init` program is running, the program does a bit of early mounting. Here's the
snippet:

```
CHECKCALL(mount("tmpfs", "/dev", "tmpfs", MS_NOSUID, "mode=0755")); //Mount tmpfs
[...]
CHECKCALL(mount("devpts", "/dev/pts", "devpts", 0, NULL)); //Mount devpts
[...]
CHECKCALL(mount("sysfs", "/sys", "sysfs", 0, NULL)); //Mount sys
CHECKCALL(mount("selinuxfs", "/sys/fs/selinux", "selinuxfs", 0, NULL));//Mount SeLinuxFS - This is what fails
```

The first mounts (tmpfs, devpts, sysfs) all mount correctly. The problem is that when selinuxfs tries to be mounted, the syscall returns "Invalid argument".

I then added some `printk()` calls to the kernel's `do_mount` function for debugging (it handles the actual mounting process). Here's the snippet.

```
long do_mount(const char *dev_name, const char *dir_name, const char *type_page, unsigned long flags, void *data_page)
{
    struct path path;
    int ret;
    ret = user_path_at(AT_FDCWD, dir_name, LOOKUP_FOLLOW, &path);
    printk("DIR_NAME: %s",path.dentry->d_iname); //log mount directories
if (ret)
        return ret;
    ret = path_mount(dev_name, &path, type_page, flags, data_page);
    path_put(&path);
    return ret;
}
```

On the first three mounts I get a correct directory, except for selinuxfs, which returns (efault). This has me stumped, as there is clearly a path for selinuxfs's mount syscall, and all of the other mount syscalls actually do work. Also, the /sys/fs path does exist, and the sources do build and run fine on the google "goldfish" emulator. The kernel also has inbuilt SELinux support, alongside with SELinuxFS.

The kernel configuration for this device can be found here.
[Kernel configuration on GitHub](https://github.com/DeckAndroid/android_kernel_valve_jupiter/blob/7fd09d42bdcf2e9b0aca741adaab33686f82fa7f/arch/x86/configs/jupiter_defconfig)

Comment: Is it possible that your kernel is built without SELinux support?

Comment: No. The kernel configuration has CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX. I will update the question with the exact kernel configuration.

Comment: Ok.  Is it possible that SELinux has been disabled via kernel boot parameter (`selinux=0`)?

Comment: Nope, the boot parameters are very simple - just specifying the kernel and the first stage init, as filesystem initialization is handled by the fstab. However, if you require the full kernel boot config, I could post it.

Comment: Ok. It looks like you are trying to mount selinuxfs directly, but I think it is usual to go through [libselinux](https://selinuxproject.org/page/LibselinuxAPISummary) to mount it (one of the behaviors of `selinux_init_load_policy()`).  Perhaps it knows something you (and I) don't.  Do you get better results if you go that route?

Comment: The code is from the AOSP, and it is one of the first steps of boot. The policy and other stuff is loaded in the second stage init, where a lot of other libraries are available (because the root partition is remounted when initializing second stage init). That means that while this mount is required for the system and I cannot move it (it would break a lot of other code in init), the policy isn't actually loading yet.

Comment: Well, [libselinux mounts selinuxfs](https://github.com/SELinuxProject/selinux/blob/1d2073557d7199a5cc3ecce9c0cba6cb45a3e726/libselinux/src/load_policy.c#L283) with some mount options that you are not using.  I don't know whether that explains your issue.  You might also want to confirm that the kernel you are actually booting is really configured as you think.  But I don't see anything inherently wrong with your `mount()` call.